# What are some good text chat libraries or platforms?

Tags: text, chat

I'm interested in building a text chat application along the lines of AIM, facebook chat, etc, and I'm wondering where a good place to start would be.

Thanks!

Comment: what technology? java, .net, php?

Comment: Not enough information...do you want to do it online, as a desktop app, or perhaps in mobile?  Do you want to use a specific technology/programming language? Why are you building it, what do you hope to do that AIM and facebook can't? Is it 'for fun' with an aim to get friends on it?  We need a bit more information to shove you off in the direction! :)

Comment: @EmmanuelN Preferably Java; The only programming language I know right now is Groovy which is very similar. Cpfohl, A desktop App, and I'm just building it for fun. Sort of interested in how it works is all. :)

Comment: Check out [this](http://www.java-sources.net/open-source/chat-servers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One word. [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/).

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for resources to help learn it? :)

Comment: Benjamin I believe XMPP.org menus XMPP protocols (RFCs), Libraries and Resources is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a chat client with both server and client parts in Java, and our company uses one based in Delphi, so I would recommend either of those.

If you use Java, I would recommend using EclipseRCP to create a GUI quickly, and Delphi is already great for GUI's with it's forms.